# How to trigger a function with multiple Event Handler (change)

Tags: javascript

I would like to add the condition, that the function is only triggered if both
`addEventListener('change', SwitchG)` Events are True (=both have changed).
The code which I use currently activates the function already when one of the two has changed.

```
var hallo = document.getElementById("S131_01");
var hallo1 = document.getElementById("S130_01");

hallo.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);
hallo1.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);

function SwitchG () {
    var test1 = document.getElementById("submit");                                                                             
  test1.classList.add("css");   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another variable, which checks if both have been changed and only executes the handler function if both changes already happened:

```
var hallo = document.getElementById("S131_01");
var hallo1 = document.getElementById("S130_01");
var countChanges = 0; // <-- this tracks changes

hallo.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);
hallo1.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);

function SwitchG () {
  countChanges += 1;  // <-- count up
  if (countChanges >= 2) {
    countChanges = 0; // <-- reset (if needed)

    var test1 = document.getElementById("submit");                                                                             
    test1.classList.add("css"); 
  }  
}
```

A more robust implementation however, also tracks the elements which changed and ensures a repeating `change` event from *a single element* won't succeed to run the handler.

For example with this utility:

```
function ChangedCounter (minChanges) {
  var elements = new Set();
  return {
    changed(element) {
      elements.add(element);
    },
    clear() {
      elements.clear();
    },
    isReady() {
      return elements.size >= minChanges;
    }
  };
}
```

You'd write it like this:

```
var hallo = document.getElementById("S131_01");
var hallo1 = document.getElementById("S130_01");
var countChanges = ChangedCounter(2);

hallo.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);
hallo1.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);

function SwitchG (e) {
  countChanges.changed(e.target);
  if (countChanges.isReady()) {
    countChanges.clear();

    var test1 = document.getElementById("submit");                                                                             
    test1.classList.add("css"); 
  }  
}
```

Comment: What it just one of the inputs trigger the `change` event twice?

Comment: @mthrsj In that case, you also have to track which element caused the change and only update the `countChanges` variable if the element hasn't been changed already. If OP needs it, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The OP have been clear: He needs to add the class when `both events are True(=both have changed) `

Comment: @mthrsj Yes, but that's what my code already did. However, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "state" to store when the both has changed. I've created two variables, `halloState` and `hallo1State`. The snippet below shows how it could be done:

```js
var hallo = document.getElementById("S131_01");
var hallo1 = document.getElementById("S130_01");
var halloState = false;
var hallo1State = false;

hallo.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);
hallo1.addEventListener('change', SwitchG);

function SwitchG (e) {
   if(e.target.id === "S131_01")  halloState = true;
   else if(e.target.id === "S130_01")  hallo1State = true;

   if(halloState && hallo1State){
      var test1 = document.getElementById("submit");                                                           
      test1.classList.add("css");   
   }
}
```

```css
.css {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<input id="S131_01" type="text"/>
<input id="S130_01" type="text"/>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```